# How to scrape different pages using BeautifulSoup when the source has an inconsistent format?

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape data from several pages where the structure of the pages vary, not totally different, but not exactly the same. My code only goes through all the pages where len(d)==7 and skips others, where d is  d = soup.findAll('span', class_='property__base-info__value').
How can I get all the pages?! Is it possible to introduce variables which do not exist on a page and then give them NA value?!
This is my code:

```
A=[]
B=[]
C=[]
D=[]
E=[]
F=[]
G=[]
H=[]
I=[]
J=[]
K=[]
L=[]

url =   

['https://www.booli.se/annons/2272818','https://www.booli.se/annons/2082826'] 

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for page in url: 
    request = requests.get(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text,'lxml')
    #
    d = soup.findAll('span', class_='property__base-info__value')
    if len(d)==7:
        #
        region=soup.findAll('span', itemprop='name')   
        [1].text.strip().encode('utf-8')  ###region###
        #
        a = soup.findAll('span', class_='property__base-info__title__size')
        ar = a[0].text.strip().encode('utf-8').split()
        room=ar[0]  ######Rooms#####
        area=ar[2]  #####Area#####
        #
        temp=[]
        d = soup.findAll('span', class_='property__base-info__value')
        for i in d:
            i = i.text.strip()
            temp.append(i)
        #
        full_date=temp[0].encode('utf-8')
        import datetime as dt
        date=dt.datetime.strptime(full_date, '%d %b %Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')    
        #
        tempo = temp[1].split('\n')[0].encode('utf-8')
        Utropspris=tempo.replace('kr','')
        import re
        estimate=re.sub(r'(\d)\s+(\d)', r'\1\2', Utropspris) 
        #
        avgift=temp[2].encode('utf-8').replace('kr/m\xc3\xa5n','')
        fee=re.sub('(?<=\d) (?=\d)', '',avgift) ####avgift####
        #
        apt=[]
        lag=temp[3].encode('utf-8')
        if lag=='L\xc3\xa4genhet':
            apt='apartment'        ######Property type##########
        #
        cost=temp[4].encode('utf-8').replace('kr/m\xc3\xa5n','') 
        #
        floor=temp[5].encode('utf-8').replace('tr','')  
        #
        year=temp[6].encode('utf-8')   ###Year built####
        #
        test=soup.find('span', class_='property__base-info__sub- 
        value').text.strip().encode('utf-8').replace('kr/m\xc2\xb2','')
        krm2=re.sub('(?<=\d) (?=\d)', '',test)   
        #
        main=soup.find('span', class_='property__base- 
        info__title__price').text.strip().split('\n')[0].encode('utf- 
        8').replace('kr','')
        price=re.sub('(?<=\d) (?=\d)', '',main)  ####sold price####
        #
        A.append(region)
        B.append(room)
        C.append(area)
        D.append(date)
        E.append(estimate)
        F.append(fee)
        G.append(apt)
        H.append(cost)
        I.append(floor)
        J.append(year)
        K.append(krm2)
        L.append(price)
```

**Update** (from self-answer)

I can change the limit. But it won't give me the correct output. `len(d)==7` is for the case where I get full information of everything. If I set it on five, for one house I may get:

```
room, area, cost(Driftskostnad), floor (Våning),estimated price (Utropspris)
```

and for another house:

```
room, area, fee (avgift), year built (Byggår), estimated price (Utropspris)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you're asking to scrape data that you're not sure exists.
Computers are the dumbest things in the universe.

You said your code *ONLY* goes through pages where len(d)==7. Can you set the another limit?

> Is it possible to introduce variables which do not exist on a page and
>   then give them NA value?!

Yes, you can check whether elements(fields)  exist or not with a simple `if VARIABLE==None:` or just `if Variable:` (if it has any data should return true)
Hopefully, that answers your question. You're gonna have to go a little bit into details so I'd answer the question correctly, edit your question and I'll respond.

Comment: If something does not exist variable==None does not work. I think it should be variable==[].

Comment: Well it's an empty list.